# What does "corking" mean in "UDP tracks corking status"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udp

What does **corking** mean in **UDP tracks corking status**?

UDP tracks **corking** status through the pending variable.
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1e0c14f49d6b393179f423abbac47f85618d3d46

Answer (score 2):

`UDP_CORK` is a UDP socket option that allows you to accumulate data, only transmitting it
in a single datagram when the option is disabled.

(There's also the similar `MSG_MORE` flag for `send` that behaves similarly, accumulating data until a call is performed without the flag, as well as `TCP_CORK` for TCP).

The pending variable in this case is being used by the UDP code to keep track of whether data is pending transmission (i.e, if it was previously corked) or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on [Hastrkun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20270/hasturkun), from the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html):

```
UDP_CORK (since Linux 2.5.44)
      If this option is enabled, then all data output on this
      socket is accumulated into a single datagram that is
      transmitted when the option is disabled.  This option
      should not be used in code intended to be portable.
```